# WPF + PRISM - show modal popup window with controls in it?

Tags: wpf, popup, prism

I am following the *'Stock Trader RI'* example by the Prism team,
but it does not address this exactly :

I have a ***Shell*** with a ***Main Region*** in it.

In this shell I have some filter fields and a grid.

When I press on a button - I would like to load a screen that allows me to change the filters,

and then press *'Save'*. This would then call a service to update the fields, and close the pop-up.

Here is an illustration of the 'Shell' before pressing the button (left) and after (right) :

[image: Illustration:]

Problems are :

1. The 'Stock Trader RI' sample app only uses a modaless dialog popup. I need a **MODAL** pop-up (background will continue to refresh, but user will not have access to it as long as pop-up is active).
2. Need to have Silverlight-like effect when pop-up shows, meaning - 'Shell' needs to appear 'disabled' (like a gray mask over it).
3. Pop-up window should have no 'X' button and no 'minimize' or 'maximize' buttons. The pop-up window should be simply a rectangle with curved-corners.
4. I don't think I can use a 'Notification Window' or a 'Confirmation Window' because I cannot put inside them whatever I want. This is an example with 2 fields, but the pop-up might be much more complex with tabs, and a lot of information shown to the user.

So how do I show a modal pop-up from my "WPF+PRISM" Shell-View-Model once the 'Edit' button is pressed ? (Meaning, once the 'EditCommand' is executed...)

Comment: Have you looked at the Extended WPF toolkit http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/ ... you could use the ChildWindow control....restyle it if you don't want the Caption, X button, etc.

Comment: Could also try this: http://techiethings.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/web-style-wpf-popup.html ... it uses an Adorner that provides popup modal behaviour with background dimming.

Comment: And use InteractionRequest in Prism to drive the modal popup: http://blogs.southworks.net/aadami/2012/05/09/prism-interactionrequest-and-popupmodalwindowaction-for-wpf-applications/

Comment: @colinsmith - thanks for your input. I have found the solution in a link inside your last comment ...

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution [here](http://blogs.southworks.net/dcherubini/2012/05/24/popupwindowaction-using-custom-views-instead-of-windows-in-wpf-and-prism/).

Basically it uses **InteractionRequest** and it allows me to open a window (that I can style however I want, without the 'Maximize' 'Minimize buttons), and also - I can choose for it to be *Modal*.

Great thing about this solution is - that I can use custom pop-ups and not only Notification or Confirmation pop-ups.

Also - I can pass information back to the class the invoked the 'InteractionRequest'.

Only thing that it doesn't solve - is that I cannot make the calling view look disabled by adding a gray semi-transparent over it ... haven't figured out yet how to do that...

Comment: For the gray out, i created a pub sub event that links the request, to the parent window. So parent window has a subscription to a gray out event. Not very MVVM friendly, but it gets the job done

Comment: Link to solution doesn't exist